# Access variables within decorated function from the decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm quite new to Python and have just started learn about decorators. I'm trying to access a variable from the decorator itself while the code is running, in order to perform validations on the variable from the decorator.

For reasons of confidentiality I can't post the code, but  the code below explains what I want to achieve. (Obviously the code is not working)

```
def validation_func(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func(*args, **kwargs)

            if wrapper.answer == 1337:
                print ('1337')
            else:
                print('Hi')
return wrapper


@validation_func
def math_add():
   answer = 1336 + 1
```

Can I by any chance reach the variable "answer" from the function that I decorate (math_add) and perform the validations in a way similar to the code example? Or is it impossible to do that since the decorator won't recognize "answer" until the code has started running?

Comment: You could always pass `wrapper` as a parameter into the wrapped function.

Comment: @quamrana Their wrapped function doesn't have any parameters, though.

Comment: Well, just refactor so it does.

Comment: You cannot access local function variables outside of their scope. I smell an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. You may want to either edit this question or post a new one with the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```py
from functools import wraps

def validation_func(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            func(wrapper, *args, **kwargs)

            if wrapper.answer == 1337:
                print ('1337')
            else:
                print('Hi')
    return wrapper


@validation_func
def math_add(wrapper):
   wrapper.answer = 1336 + 1

math_add()
```

Output

```
1337
```

I fixed the obvious problems.

Note that the clients see no change in their usage, but `math_add()`, as defined, now has a parameter. (This might be confusing when programmers read this code later).

Comment: This is technically not really an answer to the question, though possibly an answer to the _actual_ underlying problem. The question was specifically about being able to access a variable local to `math_add` in the decorator, which is of course impossible. This circumvents that problem because the object referenced in `math_add` is also referenced in the decorator. An interesting hack nonetheless.

Comment: "which is of course impossible" - of course it is _not_ :-) there are a couple ways this could be done. But sure, first, an answer should explain what is the normal execution path for decorated code, and why iwhat is requested t is not an ordinary thing

Answer (score 0):

Python will create a scope with new variables when entering a function, and destroy that scope when the function exits - that include all local variables.

A decorator calls the function - and can run before and *after* the function finishes, but not *during* - not for ordinary functions.

There are some situations where variables create in a function scope can outlive it - with closures and non-local variables, or, some special function types which can be paused, returning the control to the caller, to be resumed later, as in the case of generator functions or asynchronous co-routine functions (and during this pause, the function local variables could be inspected). All these cases, however, would require transforms in the function itself: both its meta-attributes, and in its bytecode itself, in order to cause the pause itself.

This means it is something "possible but not really feasible decorators" - it can be done,but would require recompiling the function itself, and there could be lots of corner cases witch would have to be dealt with.

However, if instead of a decorator, the function is written so that it *calls*  something, with this call placed within its body, then yes, it is possible and relatively easy for the called function to inspect the caller state at the point it was called. That would be a "reverse decorator". It could even work together with a traditional decorator that would annotate the metadata about which checks should be done.

And last, but not least, the other way of doing that: one can leverage the instrumentation meant to be used by debuggers in the language: that can generate callbacks with a lot of information on the running scope.
I think that except having a "called function" instead of a decorator, this is the approach that would work. See the docs at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace

So, here is a sample decorator that could use the debugging infrastructure to do what you want, checking the local variables when a return or exception is met:

```
import sys
from functools import wraps

sentinel = object()

def validation(assertions):
    depth = 0
    def tracer(frame, event, arg):
        nonlocal depth
        if event == "call":
            depth += 1
            if depth > 1:
                return None
            frame.f_trace_lines = False
            frame.f_trace_opcodes = False
            return tracer
        # this code should only be reached for "return" and exception codes:
        for variable_name, expected_value in assertions.items():
            current_value = frame.f_locals.get(variable_name, sentinel)
            if current_value != expected_value:
                print(f"{variable_name} contains {current_value}. Expected {expected_value}")
        return tracer


    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

            sys.settrace(tracer)
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                sys.settrace(None)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@validation({"answer": 1337})
def math_add():
   answer = 1336 + 2


math_add()
```

Running the above snippet as a Python program, this is printed:

```
answer contains 1338. Expected 1337
```

Besides the documentation on sys.settrace above you probably will like to check what are the attributes available on a Frame object as well. (the `f_locals` attribute is a dictionary reflecting the contents of the local variables, for example).
https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members